# convert each sub-dictionary in a nested dictionary to defaultdict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

```
 class MyDict(dict):
        pass

 def nest_dict(dct):
     dct = MyDict(dct)
     for k, v in dct.items():
         if isinstance(v, dict):
             dct[k] = MyDict(v)
             nest_dict(v)
     return dct 

dct = {'a':{'b':{'c':'d'}}}
print(type(nest_dict(dct)['a']['b']))
```

Here's a piece of code I have now. What I want to do is covert each sub-dictionary in a nested dictionary to a child class of dict, which is MyDict. 
However, my recursion logic only change the first level of sub dictionary. How to modify this recursion function?

Comment: An obvious flaw is that you never invoke the `nest_dict()` function. Also, `pass` is misspelled. Also, `dct['a']['b']['c']` is the string `d`. It will never be affected by `nest_dict()`. Please create a short, complete program that actually runs and actually demonstrates your question. Copy-paste that program (never retype) into your question along with its actual and hoped-for output. See [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not updating your nested structures properly, try:

```
def nest_dict(dct):
    dct = MyDict(dct)
    for k, v in dct.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            dct[k] = nest_dict(v)
    return dct

dct = {'a': {'b': {'c': 'd'}}}
print(type(dct['a']['b']))  # <class 'dict'>
my_dct = nest_dict(dct)
print(type(my_dct['a']['b']))  # <class '__main__.MyDict'>
```

Although I'd advise you not to extend `dict` and use [`collections.MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.MutableMapping) instead. On Python 3.x it's moved to [`collections.abc.MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableMapping).

Comment: This works well for me. Thanks a lot. I will try to learn MutableMapping. Could you tell more detail about why my solution fail?

Answer (score 0):

You could use depth-first search to traverse the `dict`.

```
class MyDict(dict):
    pass

dct = {'a':{'b':{'c':'d'}}}


def nest_dict(dct):
    dct = res = MyDict(dct)
    candidates = [(k, dct) for k in dct]
    while candidates:
        k, dct = candidates.pop()
        if isinstance(dct[k], dict):
            dct[k] = MyDict(dct[k])
            candidates.extend((k_, dct[k]) for k_ in dct[k])

    return res

dct2 = nest_dict(dct)
```

Answer (score 0):

define a function dict_to_defaultdict(), inside the function looping it through